# jQuery mobile- How to change the icon of select to a custom icon?

Tags: jquery-mobile, icons, font-awesome

I have to change the select icon in `<select>` to a fa icon.
The code I use:

```
<select class="sortBy" name="sortBy" data-url="${url}" data-icon="ui-icon-arrow-sort">
        <option value="">Sort By</option>
        <option value="new" selected="selected">Newest</option>
        <option value="old">Oldest</option>
</select>
```

The CSS is:

```
.ui-icon-arrow-sort{
    content: "\f0dd";
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

For now it's not working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Font-Awesome icons aren't SVG, they can't be used as `background-image` as jQM icons. However, you still can override arrow icon in `select`, but it requires JS to add custom class to *button* within `select`.

First, add `data-icon="false"` to `select` to prevent jQM from adding arrow icon. Then, on `pagecreate`, add your custom class to `select`'s button.

```css
.ui-icon-arrow-sort:after {
  content:"\f0dd";
  font: normal normal normal 20px/1 FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 30px;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```js
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
    $(".sortBy", this).closest(".ui-btn").addClass("ui-icon-arrow-sort");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/m6kL2x8p/)**

Comment: @Omar- I know Awesome icons aren't SVG. As u can see I didn't use it as background image. I follow according custom icon in http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html. It supposed to work...

Comment: @SaritRotshild the demo is outdated, 1.1 is an obsolete version.